# What is the proper way of moving my content but not my header/footer?

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr

My header and footer are all set. Size and position are good. However, I want to push the actual content to the right and down (creating big margins at the top and left of the document). See this final result I have in mind:

[image]

The geometry package is very useful at changing page margins, but it will also move my header/footer (using the fancyhdr package BTW). What is the proper package/command to use when only moving the content itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://www.writelatex.com/168308hkpsnd ?(you may be able to guess from the graphical look if that is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The package `fancyhdr` offers you a declaration possibility for this:

```
\fancyheadoffset[RO,LE]{<length>}
```

where `<length>` is the value you want to see header being extended and the optional argument specifies in which direction (e.g., `RO` means to the right on odd-numbered pages).
Similar command exists for footers. If you use the `calc` package the length can be given as something like

```
\markinparsep+\marginparwith
```

making the specification fairly painless.

Actually, the way you phrased the question: you need to start setting the `\textwidth` to the width that you want your content to be and position it using, for example, `geometry` where you want it placed. Then the above command adjusts the header size but doesn't change the content placement.